# Can't create a New Project or File - First Screen Empty NB 7.1.1 and 7.1.2

Tags: 12.04, netbeans

The first screen in the wizard is blank or empty, only shows me Cancel 
button. I'm Working in UBUNTU 12.04.

I reinstalled Netbeans and the problem is still there, I tried with NB 7.1.1 and NB 7.1.2. I'm using Oracle JDK 7.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird! That might be related to **memory usage**, a **broken JDK installation** a **broken LAF** (Nimbus or GTK+)..Can't tell. Please provide more details. Netbeans 7.1.x works perfectly under 12.04.
When Netbeans is started, click on the red icon on right bottom. This will reveal a dialog with details about eventual startup errors. and paste it in your question.

[image: Broken Netbeans GUI]

Meanwhile can you start your netbeans using this command and tell us what the result is:

```
/bin/sh "/your_netbeans_home_directory/bin/netbeans -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd --laf Metal"
```

- What JDK do you use?
- Does the same problem happen with Netbeans 7.0.1?
- Did you install downloaded Netbeans using root privileges : sudo /bin/sh /netbeans-7.x-installer.sh
- When you run Netbeans, How much RAM do you have left?

I'll update my answer dependently on your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was the LAF when I use LAF Metal  everything is ok. I'm using JDK 1.7 in fact i did what you posted here http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/netbeans-ide-look-feel-under-ubuntu-12-04/ thanks =D

Comment: @MaxJRB Glad I could help. You're welcome :) Could you please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I have a very similar issue, but the proposed solutin isn't working for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/326556/i-cant-start-a-new-project-on-netbeans