# I can't start a new project on Netbeans

Tags: 12.04, netbeans

### The issue:

When I open the "add new project" dialog (screenshot below), I can't create a new project. The loading message (hourglass icon) stays on forever. Except for "cancel", the other buttons are disabled.

It was working fine a few days ago, I haven't changed any setting prior to the issue appearing. I ran the internal update feature, but the issue persists.

[image]

### The info:

**My OS version**: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 64 bits

**Netbeans version**:

Help -> about

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 (Build 201210100934)
Java: 1.6.0_27; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 20.0-b12
System: Linux version 3.2.0-49-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; pt_BR (nb)
User directory: /home/user/.netbeans/7.2.1
Cache directory: /home/user/.cache/netbeans/7.2.1
```

### What I tried:

- Changing the Look and Feel with the `--laf` command-line option. The look-and-feel does change, but the issue persists.
- Using the internal update command, a plugin got updated but the issue persists.
- Downloading and installing the latest version (7.31), it imported the settings from the previous version and the issue persists.
- Removing the settings folder `~/.netbeans/7.3.1`, restarting netbeans, choosing not to import settings and rather have a new clean install

Comment: HIGHLY relevant: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=122202

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just posted the same question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326933/netbeans-broken-after-openjdk-update) ... the solution for me was to downgrade OpenJDK from **6b27** to **6b24** (look at the link for details).

My NetBeans was looking ***excactly*** like in your sreenshot and also had some other strange problems.

I would suggest you do `java -version` if this shows that you have **6b27** installed and `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep openjdk` shows that you recently received the OpenJDK update you can try to fix the problem reverting to **6b24** using this command:

```
apt-get install openjdk-6-jre=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 openjdk-6-jre-headless=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 icedtea-6-jre-cacao=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2
```

****edit****

As I discovered some other problems (SSH connection wouldn't establish within NetBeans) I finally took the step to upgrade to Oracle JDK7. To start NetBeans with another JDK you have got to edit `./netbeans-7.X/etc/netbeans.conf` and change the line `netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre"` (I guess this gets generated in the NetBeans installation process). Otherwise it will still use your old JDK no matter what `java -version` says.

Comment: Good suggestion! You may also want to try Java 7, since JDK 7 and the OpenJDK equivalent have been released for quite a long time now, so there's really no reason to stick with Java 6.x.

Comment: @somequixotic I updated to it on my notebook, but for some reason the problems with NetBeans weren't gone. Perhaps it was still using OpenJDK under the hood?

`java -version` showed `java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: Aha! `dpkg.log` shows `upgrade openjdk-6-jre-lib 6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2` and two similar others on July 24th, one day before I left on a short vacation, nad Netbeans was working. Might be the culprit!

Comment: @ruda.almeida The downgrade solved the problem with the new projects for me, but later one I had other problems (with SSH), so the real final solution for me was to install `openjdk-7-jre` (or the oracle version - both work) and change the path in the `netbeans.conf`.

Comment: Just in case: For me works installing "sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre", but the with path in config file as:  netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre", instead of the one you put in your answer

Comment: @gsc-leticia Jeah, that makes sense. The path in my question was for the oracle version and not for OpenJDK.

Comment: @s1lv3r sure, just for archive purpose :)

Comment: I changed it to netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre" but now netbeans is not starting. The path is correct though. Any help?

Comment: @neo1691 Can you try starting it via the command line and see it it produces any output?

Comment: I fixed it by installing the jdk. Only jre was present

Comment: I had same problem solved with this answer but also I had to remove  /home/username/.netbeans directory with old user settings. Because after moving to newer java version netbeans tried to start but suddenly closed at startup. Removing old settings alows netbeans to recreate them and all is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's [a bug caused by the JDK](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=122202#c16) version used:

> This problem is JDK bug with focus (never ending loop when requesting focus). Issue filed against JDK is https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6598089. (IcedTea and in future OpenJDK will be distributed as default JDK for Linux distribution so it should be supported.)

The bug seems to affect both Oracle JDK and OpenJDK. Update your JDK in order to fix it. (Don't forget to chante the `netbeans_jdkhome` variable in the `./netbeans-7.X/etc/netbeans.conf` file!)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your Netbeans' Swing [Look and Feel](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBLookAndFeels) to Nimbus.

Comment: Tried Nimbus, Metal, GTK, etc. The look and feel changes, but the unclickable buttons and eternal loading persists.

Comment: what version of Netbeans? anything on the console when you run netbeans from the console?

Comment: Nothing on the console if started from the command line.

Comment: do you have any important projects prior to this lock up?

Comment: @mojo706 No, and the ones I had are backed-up

Comment: try a reinstall then? Works most of the time.

Comment: @mojo706 As stated in the question, I did.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue last night one Ubuntu 13.04

I have openjdk 6 installed and the install was successful but netbeans hung when I tried to create a new project.

Today I managed to solve it after screaming at my computer and scaring my girlfriend :)

Pretty sure this solved it.

Go to https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/install.html#install_windows and you'll see that you need to `chmod` the installer:

```
chmod +x installer-file-name
```

before you install...

```
sh installer-file-name
```

Once I did this I got an executable netbeans on my desktop (for some reason not listed in applications).

One thing to note about the installer, for me it said it couldn't get access to some JUNIT packages, i selected 'quit these modules' or something similar, and the rest of the installation worked fine.

I hope this solves your issue too!

Comment: I had to `chmod +x` the installer or it wouldn't even install the new version. That's not the cause of my issue.

Comment: @Ruda, the only other thing I did differently was installing netbeans prior to any other updates (ie I reinstalled ubuntu, and only installed the jdks (6 and 7) before installing netbeans).

Other things to try:

Run the installer with jdk7 and 6 and see if anything happens differently between them.

Sorry my answer didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

I've been having this problem for a couple of days and it's been totally winding me up.

Just resolved it however by changing my version of Java from OpenJDK to Oracle

These might help you -

http://kiranscience.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/remove-openjdkjre-from-ubuntu-1204.html

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: ... forgot to mention, then either have to reinstall netbeans or update netbeans.conf to use new jre

Comment: It looks like a valid answer to me.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by upgrading to open-jdk 7.

Answer (score -1):

I had run in to the same problem and a few others trying to get Netbeans to work on 12.04LTS, this is how I managed to have a full working copy.

I (please don't shot me) used a windows device to download the full Netbeans package from the Netbeans website.

I then transferred the .sh file to my desktop, then I needed to change the permissions to allow the file to be executed, with;

```
sudo chmod +x netbeans-7.4-linux.sh
```

then I simply installed the file with;

```
./netbeans-7.4-linux.sh
```

Netbeans does not show up in applications but there is a launcher on the desktop.

Hope this is of some help to someone :)

Answer (score -1):

For me changing

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64"
```

to

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
```

in the netbeans.conf file worked. :) :)

Comment: This answer is incomplete as it stands, It will only work if you already have Java 7 installed, if you are using openJDK, if your processor architecture is amd64, etc.