# netbeans broken after openjdk update

Tags: openjdk, netbeans

I had some strange issues on my notebook where NetBeans hangs some times and also some dialog items are missing. I tried various things (ugrading to jre-7, switching to oracle jre, other versions of Netbeans - anything from 7.0 to 7.3) but nothing helped.

Today I updated my main PC (both are under 12.04 64bit) and it suddenly shows the same problems. So the problem must be connected to the update. I had a look at the dpkg.log and saw, that I got a new openjdk version.

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log

2013-07-31 12:38:19 configure openjdk-6-jre 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2 <none>
2013-07-31 12:38:19 status unpacked openjdk-6-jre 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2
2013-07-31 12:38:19 status half-configured openjdk-6-jre 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2
2013-07-31 12:38:19 status installed openjdk-6-jre 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2
2013-07-31 12:38:19 configure openjdk-6-jdk 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2 <none>
2013-07-31 12:38:19 status unpacked openjdk-6-jdk 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2
2013-07-31 12:38:19 status half-configured openjdk-6-jdk 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2
2013-07-31 12:38:20 status installed openjdk-6-jdk 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2
```

So I reverted the update using:

```
apt-cache showpkg openjdk-6-jre 
apt-get install openjdk-6-jre=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2
```

But the problem still persists. Has anybody ever had a similiar problem or an idea to resolve this?

Best regards,
Malte

*** EDIT ***

I just saw that `java -version` still shows

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

So it seems the downgrade didn't work out. Do I need to downgrade any other packages?

I'm unable to install a **6b24** package of `icedtea6-jre-cacao` via `apt-get install`.

Comment: Have you tried using Java Sun instead?

Comment: Yes, I tried Sun/Oracle JRE on my notebook. No change.

Comment: @s1lv3r - are you able to update within program netbeans ? - there is in menue of "help" this option "check for updates" - can you try with this ?

Comment: It says the installation is up to date. Also the problem occurs under any NetBeans version (tested 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3). It really must be related to the JRE version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't start a new project on Netbeans](http://askubuntu.com/questions/326556/i-cant-start-a-new-project-on-netbeans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

Had to use:

```
apt-cache policy icedtea-6-jre-cacao
```

To find the right version string to perform a downgrade. For some reason `apt-cache showpkg` and `apt-show-versions` didn't show it.

So the final commands to fix this problem where:

```
apt-cache showpkg openjdk-6-jre 
apt-cache policy icedtea-6-jre-cacao
```

To find the right version to downgrade to. And:

```
apt-get install openjdk-6-jre=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 openjdk-6-jre-headless=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2 icedtea-6-jre-cacao=6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2
```

To perform the downgrade.

After downgrading from ***6b27*** to ***6b24*** the problems in NetBeans are resolved for me on both PCs.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my netbeans using a similar command in debian!

Comment: @neo1691 You may also consider upgrading to JRE7. I had some other problems with Netbeans after the above solution and upgrading solved them for me. Here is further reading: http://askubuntu.com/questions/326556/i-cant-start-a-new-project-on-netbeans